# Serverless + Typescriptを使用したjson schemaのバリデーションチェックエラーについて

Tags: json, typescript, aws-lambda

Serverless + Typescriptを使用した際にバリデーションチェックエラーについて行き詰っており、ご相談させてください。

frameworkVersion:3
serverlessのテンプレートから作成
※テンプレートから作成した状態から説明いたします

curlを使用してPostリクエストをおこなった場合に下記エラーとなります。
このエラーをソース側で開発者が定義したエラーに変更する方法はございませんでしょうか
※Postリクエストのbodyにnameを指定していないのでことで発生させています

```
{"errorMessage":"Request body validation failed: requires property \"name\"","errorType":"Error","offlineInfo":"If you believe this is an issue with serverless-offline please submit it, thanks. https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues"
```

目的としては、validationエラーを開発者が定義したエラーメッセージに変更したいです。

試したこと（どれも上手くいかず・・）
・middyのonErrorでハンドリング
・@middy/http-error-handlerを使用してハンドリング

ご助力よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 関連するソースコード

■schema.ts

```
export default {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    name: { type: 'string', minLength: 1  },
    bangou: {
      type: 'number',
    },
  },
  required: ['name']
} as const;
```

■handler.ts

```
import type { ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { formatJSONResponse } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { middyfy } from '@libs/lambda';

import schema from './schema';

const hello: ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<typeof schema> = async (event) => {
  return formatJSONResponse({
    message: `Hello ${event.body.name}, welcome to the exciting Serverless world!`,
    event,
  });
};

export const main = middyfy(hello);
```

■lambda.ts

```
import middy from "@middy/core"
import middyJsonBodyParser from "@middy/http-json-body-parser"

export const middyfy = (handler) => {
  return middy(handler).use(middyJsonBodyParser())
}
```

■api-gateway.ts

```
import type { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult, Handler } from "aws-lambda"
import type { FromSchema } from "json-schema-to-ts";

type ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S> = Omit<APIGatewayProxyEvent, 'body'> & { body: FromSchema<S> }
export type ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S> = Handler<ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S>, APIGatewayProxyResult>
export const formatJSONResponse = (response: Record<string, unknown>) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(response)
  }
}
```

■index.ts

```
import schema from './schema';
import { handlerPath } from '@libs/handler-resolver';

export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  events: [
    {
      http: {
        method: 'post',
        path: 'hello',
        request: {
          schemas: {
            'application/json': schema,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```